# iOS Quartz PDF add file and destination links to a new pdf

Tags: ios, pdf, hyperlink, anchor, quartz-graphics

i use this code below to parse a PDF file and extract three different types of URI's/data.

**1) Normal URL**

**2) Anchor within the PDF**

**3) A file link example "../other.pdf"**

See Code here:
http://pastebin.com/LMJtVGZw

--

Due to a user requirement i create a PDF file within my application and i need to insert the three mentioned types of URI's/data.

**1) Normal URL can be created with these lines of code**

http://pastebin.com/HdetkSvT

**2) Anchor, this code doen't work and i'm not able to parse it (See case #2 above)**
http://pastebin.com/DfZwsK33

**3) A file link example "../other.pdf"**

I have no idea :-(

I hope someone can help me to get #2 and #3 working.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, your pasted code contains only the `CGPDFContextAddDestinationAtPoint`

code where you define the anchor. This will actually not generate anything in the PDF file (it's not like HTML where the anchor is something that is present in the HTML code somewhere).

Did you also use `CGPDFContextSetDestinationForRect` to setup the actual link annotation? This is the one that should generate the actual PDF objects in the file...